# Spfx webpart to fetch list data from different site collection

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-webparts, cross-site

I need to create a spfx webpart which fetch data from a list avaialble on different site collectionn.
Ex: SPFx webpart deployed at https://test.sharepoint.com/sites/test1

List from where data need to be fetch is at site :
https://test.sharepoint.com/sites/test2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did sample test.

The script would get data from another site collection while there is potential issue, SPFx use current user credential to access SharePoint data, so if current user has no permission to target site collection, there would be issue.

```
this.props.context.spHttpClient.get(`https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/modernteam/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('List1')/items?select=ID,Title`,
      SPHttpClient.configurations.v1).then((response: SPHttpClientResponse) => {
        response.json().then((responseJSON: any) => {
          // to do
        });
      });
```

So, you may consider to use search/Microsoft graph instead.

[Search in SPFx](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/sharepoint-framework-retrieve-search-results/)

[Call graph api in SPFx](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/use-aad-tutorial)

Comment: In this we gave hard core link, is there any other way we can achieve this without giving any link directly?

Comment: You may create a custom property so you could set the url dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using OfficeOpenXml;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string username = "your-username";
        string password = "your-password";
        string outputFilePath = "Path\\To\\Your\\OutputFile.xlsx";
        string excelFilePath = "Path\\To\\Your\\SiteUrls.xlsx";
        string targetContentTypeName = "YourContentTypeName";

    using (var package = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(excelFilePath)))
    {
        var worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[0];
        int rowCount = worksheet.Dimension.Rows;

        using (var outputPackage = new ExcelPackage())
        {
            for (int row = 1; row <= rowCount; row++)
            {
                string siteUrl = worksheet.Cells[row, 1].Text.Trim();

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(siteUrl))
                {
                    using (var context = new ClientContext(siteUrl))
                    {
                        // Provide credentials
                        var credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(username, ConvertToSecureString(password));
                        context.Credentials = credentials;

                        // Load web and retrieve all pages with specific content type
                        var web = context.Web;
                        var pagesLibrary = web.Lists.GetByTitle("Site Pages");

                        // Retrieve the content type by name
                        ContentType contentType = GetContentTypeByName(context, web, targetContentTypeName);
                        if (contentType != null)
                        {
                            // Construct CAML query to filter pages by content type
                            var pagesQuery = new CamlQuery
                            {
                                ViewXml = $@"<View>
                                                <Query>
                                                    <Where>
                                                        <Eq>
                                                            <FieldRef Name='ContentTypeId' />
                                                            <Value Type='ContentTypeId'>{contentType.Id.StringValue}</Value>
                                                        </Eq>
                                                    </Where>
                                                </Query>
                                            </View>"
                            };

                            var pages = pagesLibrary.GetItems(pagesQuery);
                            context.Load(pages);
                            context.ExecuteQuery();

                            // Create a new worksheet for each site in the output Excel file
                            var outputWorksheet = outputPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(GetSafeSheetName(siteUrl));

                            // Add headers to the output sheet
                            outputWorksheet.Cells["A1"].Value = "Page URL";
                            outputWorksheet.Cells["B1"].Value = "Web Part Title";

                            int outputRow = 2;

                            // Loop through each page
                            foreach (var page in pages)
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    var pageFile = page.File;
                                    context.Load(pageFile, f => f.ServerRelativeUrl);
                                    context.ExecuteQuery();

                                    // Get all web parts on the page
                                    var webParts = GetWebPartsOnPage(context, pageFile.ServerRelativeUrl);

                                    // Display information about each web part
                                    outputWorksheet.Cells[outputRow, 1].Value = pageFile.ServerRelativeUrl;
                                    foreach (var webPart in webParts)
                                    {
                                        outputWorksheet.Cells[outputRow, 2].Value = webPart.WebPart.Title;
                                        outputRow++;
                                    }
                                }
                                catch (Exception ex)
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine($"Error processing page in site {siteUrl}: {ex.Message}");
                                }

                                // Add a delay between each page (e.g., 1 second)
                                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine($"Content type '{targetContentTypeName}' not found in site {siteUrl}.");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            // Save the output Excel file
            outputPackage.SaveAs(new FileInfo(outputFilePath));
        }
    }
}

static WebPartDefinitionCollection GetWebPartsOnPage(ClientContext context, string pageUrl)
{
    var page = context.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(pageUrl);
    LimitedWebPartManager webPartManager = page.GetLimitedWebPartManager(PersonalizationScope.Shared);
    context.Load(webPartManager.WebParts, wps => wps.Include(wp => wp.WebPart.Title));
    context.ExecuteQuery();

    return webPartManager.WebParts;
}

static ContentType GetContentTypeByName(ClientContext context, Web web, string contentTypeName)
{
    var contentTypes = web.ContentTypes;
    context.Load(contentTypes, types => types.Include(type => type.Id, type => type.Name));
    context.ExecuteQuery();

    var contentType = contentTypes.FirstOrDefault(type => type.Name == contentTypeName);
    return contentType;
}

static SecureString ConvertToSecureString(string password)
{
    SecureString secureString = new SecureString();
    foreach (char c in password.ToCharArray())
    {
        secureString.AppendChar(c);
    }
    return secureString;
}

// Helper method to create a safe sheet name from the site URL
static string GetSafeSheetName(string siteUrl)
{
    return new string(siteUrl.Where(c => Char.IsLetterOrDigit(c) || c == '_').ToArray());
}
```

}